# Why doesn't the black hole in the center of the Milky Way glow similarly to the famous M87 image?

Tags: observational-astronomy, black-hole, radio-astronomy, milky-way, m87

The M87 image made some astronomers famous recently as the first image of a black hole.

In the Milky Way, it has been concluded that there must be a black hole due to the [movement of stars near the center](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B0QRpid5_QU&ab_channel=VideoFromSpace). But why is there no such light effect in our black hole, as there is in M87? Or is it there, but we cannot see it for some reason?

[image: Event Horizon Telescope image of the accretion disk around the black hole in M87]

Comment: The colours in this picture are artificial. The "light" being observed is actually millimeter waves, on the boundary being long IR and short microwaves.

Comment: [Why not take a picture of a closer black hole?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/30339/why-not-take-a-picture-of-a-closer-black-hole)

Comment: @KeithMcClary I've just asked [Will the first Event Horizon Telescope image of the Milky Way's black hole be just another orange donut?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/39352/7982) but seeing that, I've got to go back and include more in it. Thanks for the link!

Comment: This is such an interesting question! Now I've just asked [How will they know when to start taking the picture of the black hole at the center of the Milky Way?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/39354/7982)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

News were released today and a new image has been published which has similarities to the M87 image in the question.

https://eventhorizontelescope.org/blog/astronomers-reveal-first-image-black-hole-heart-our-galaxy

> Although we cannot see the event horizon itself, because it cannot emit light, glowing gas orbiting around the black hole reveals a telltale signature: a dark central region (called a “shadow”) surrounded by a bright ring-like structure. The new view captures light bent by the powerful gravity of the black hole, which is four million times more massive than our Sun. The image of the Sgr A* black hole is an average of the different images the EHT Collaboration has extracted from its 2017 observations.

Credit: EHT Collaboration

[image: Image credit: EHT Collaboration]